# Reflections Как получить экземпляр из поля?

Tags: java

`someView.getDeclaratedFields();`

возвращаем маcсив полей.

Как получить объекты на которые ссылаются эти поля?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак.

[`GetDeclaredFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) возвращает [описатели полей](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html), которые по *любому* объекту данного типа смогут произвести доступ к полю. То есть, полученные описатели подходят к *любому* объекту данного типа, и соответственно ничего ни о каком конкретном объекте не знают.

---

С другой стороны, не исключено, что у есть ссылка на объект, от которого вы получили ваш `Class`. Это и есть искомый объект. Но ни сам `Class`, ни полученные от него `Field`'ы об исходном объекте ничего не знают.

Comment: спасибо, получил доступ.

Answer (score 2):

[Здесь](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-reflection-api) очень подробно описано. Получите ссылки на объекты, но они  будут типа Object. Потом можно привести к нужному типу. Либо, используя туже рефлексию, вызывать методы/менять свойства.

И ещё статья на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69552/).

Comment: Спасибо, получил доступ.